# java programs run slower from command line than in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, latency

I know this may seem unlikely, and there is already a question about the more likely reverse phenomenon, but it really does happen with my programs and I'm utterly mystified by it.

Both JREs are 1.7.0_25, both 32-bit.  The OS is Windows 7 (64-bit).
I imagine one thought is to switch to 64-bit java.  But I'm quite scared about the disruption and general malfunctioning this might cause.  And I can't understand why just the fact of using 32-bit java should really cause a problem of this kind.

The sorts of things that happen are things like much greater latency/lagging when navigating through a JTree structure with the navigation keys, and generally everything affecting the GUI.  Everything is just more sluggish when I run it from the command line (with the same dataset by the way, so the same size of GUI structures, etc.)

Comment: Does your Eclipse launcher use different memory settings than the defaults?  The defaults are notoriously low, so the command line might need more.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I just did a bit of first experimenting with the -X CLI options... I don't know which of these I should be trying out.  "initial/maximum java heap" perhaps ?  My system has 4 GB RAM but it would not start with more than -Xmx1g (1GB maximum)... and when it ran on that setting there didn't appear to be any change... hmmm